# Solspace Rating vote up/down using AJAX

Tags: solspace, ajax, solspace-rating

I'm trying to use AJAX to streamline the Rating Vote feature of Solspace Rating so the success or error code from the `{exp:rating:insert_rating_vote}` tag.

In my {rating:entries} template I have this code for the up down voting links:

```
{exp:rating:rating_vote_stats rating_id="{rating_id}"}
{if not_already_voted}<span class="helpful"><strong>Was this review helpful?</strong><span class="voters"><a href="/vendor/rating-vote/{rating_id}/up/" class="yes">Yes</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/vendor/rating-vote/{rating_id}/down/" class="no">No</a></span><span class="ajax-response"></span></span>{/if}
{if already_voted}<span class="helpful"><strong>Was this review helpful?</strong><span class="ajax-response">Thanks for your vote</span></span>{/if}
{if total > 0}<span class="light people-like">{up_votes}/{total} people liked this review</span>{/if}
{/exp:rating:rating_vote_stats}
```

And the /vendor/rating-vote template those links point to contains this:

```
{exp:rating:insert_rating_vote
    rating_id="{segment_3}"
    allow_duplicates="no"
    duplicate_check_guest_ip="no" 
}
{if failure}Error!{/if}{if success}Thanks for your vote{/if}
{/exp:rating:insert_rating_vote}
```

This setup works as expected. When I click the link I go to that simple template which returns my failure or success message and the up/down vote is recorded and shows in my stats. I see:

> Thanks for your vote

**When I try to load the template via AJAX is doesn't work as expected.**

I'm using this JS code:

```
$(".voters .yes, .voters .no") .click (function() {
    var link = $(this).attr("href")
    var $helpful = $(this).closest(".helpful");
    $helpful.find(".ajax-response").load(link, function() {
        $helpful.find(".voters").hide();
    });
    return false;
});
```

This works except the content loaded into my span is not the same as the ouput I got before. This is what I get in my template where I would expect the simple success message:

> {"success":true,"failure":false,"message":"Your input is
>   appreciated.","already_reviewed":false,"not_already_reviewed":true,"prior_review_count":0,"count":1}

**Any advice on how to get this working?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success with a modified version of the generic ajax code linked by Solspace:

```
$(".voters .yes, .voters .no") .click (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr("href")
        var $helpful = $(this).closest(".helpful");
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            success: function(results){  
                    $helpful.find(".voters").hide();
                    $helpful.find(".ajax-response").html("Thanks for your vote");
                },
            error: function(results){
                    $helpful.find(".ajax-response").html("Error - vote not counted");
            }
        });
    });
```

However, in my `{exp:rating:insert_rating_vote}` templates I have messages for success and failure like this:

```
{exp:rating:insert_rating_vote
    rating_id="{segment_3}"
    allow_duplicates="no"
    duplicate_check_guest_ip="no" 
}
{if failure}Error!{/if}{if success}Thanks for your vote{/if}
{/exp:rating:insert_rating_vote}
```

But with this ajax method my messages where not being sent (I was seeing the default response) even when using `results` or `results.message` as the HTML output. So I ended up hard coding the response into the JS - not ideal but in my case works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$helpful.find(".ajax-response").load(link, function(response, status, xhr) {
    $helpful.find(".voters").hide();
    $helpful.find(".ajax-response").html(response.message);
});
```

Ajax submissions return a JSON array as a response. You need the correct key (in this case .message) in this array to display only text.

Another method for general-purpose ajax submissions can be found here: http://support.solspace.com/solution/categories/115922/folders/190597/articles/119581-simple-jquery-ajax-script

Comment: I've implemented this but I'm still seeing the JSON response ;-(

Comment: I still can't get this to work even with the above change. Would you mind taking another look at this one?

Comment: Did you try using console.log(response) with the above solution (within the `function (response) { ... }` of course)? This might need a rewrite. load() might not be the best function to handle the response.

Comment: I would suggest instead trying out the .ajax() method suggested in this solution's link. Adjust as needed based on your own situation.

Comment: @Solspace - The link you provided in your answer is no more reachable - you have any idea where it has moved?